# Render a pdf stream on a jsp using struts2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am using struts2 in my web application. I want to render a pdf stream on a jsp. i am currently doing this:

```
public String renderPDF() throws Exception
{
     myService.rederPDF(getServletResponse().getServletOutputStream());
     return SUCCESS;
}
```

The rederPDF method of myService gets a pdf stream and writes to the servlet response output stream. But this throws an exception that "The response has already been committed".

Comment: why don't you use stream result and input stream which is more clean and better?

Comment: i thought stream result is used for file download only. can it be used to render a pdf stream on a page?

Comment: Stream result is used to open a input stream, i believe this can be done using the above said result type

Comment: ok, let me test it, i will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when you already sent some thing to client before you forward.

I am using Servlets for downloading files. Have a look.

```
public class FileDownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    byte[] b = null;
    ServletOutputStream sop = null;

    try {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=yourFileName.pdf");          

        sop = response.getOutputStream();
        b =  myService.getFileData(); /* your code */
        sop.write(b);    
        return;         
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        /* some code*/
    }
    finally{ 
        /* some code*/
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't actually want to download this file. I want to render it on a page. I am currently using struts 2.

Comment: Rendering means, you want to show that file as a PDF view along with other page contents?

Comment: For that you have to include a iframe that will render pdf file. You can not do both things in one JSP.

Comment: Even then, I'm not sure even the major browsers all support displaying PDFs without some kind of plugins.